# Divide a Row into 2 rows inside a mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi im writing a Menu for a website wich have multiple states based on my country, and each state a lot of cities.

In the code everything is working nice.. but i have been asked to "divide" in the menu, one state, into 2 states, for example "State 1 A-L" and then "State 1 M - Z"

My first thought was to create two states in DB, so just as simple as that i will create both. But, then inside all the site I would have 2 states instead of 1, like it should be.

So I think there has to be a way to do this.. If not I will have to do an HTML menu, and then just update it manually, which sucks. It would be better if the menu autoupdated based on the query...

Here is my code and query: the order of the states, is just to get the 2 column menu i need. But how can I "divide" or "split" a state and make it two?

```
 <?php  
$result = mysqli_query($con ,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'"); 


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_states WHERE ccode='MX' Order by find_in_set(scode, '01,17,02,18,03,19,04,20,05,21,06,22,07,23,08,24,09,25,10,26,11,27,12,28,13,29,14,30,15,31,33,32,16')");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{?>

<li class="menuin<?php echo $row['sname'];?>"><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $row['sname'];?></a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN<?php echo $row['sname'];?>" id="menusub<?php echo $row['sname'];?>">
        <?php $resultSub = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table_cities` where ccode='$row[ccode]' and scode='$row[scode]' limit 0,30");
        //echo "SELECT * FROM `table_cities` where ccode='$row[ccode]' and scode='$row[scode]' limit 0,30";
        while($rowSub = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSub)){
        ?>  
        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/<?php echo $rowSub['id'];?>&<?php echo $row['scode'];?>&city=<?php echo $rowSub['city'];?>"><?php echo $rowSub['city'];?></a></li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
</li>

<?php   }
?>
</ul> 
</div>  
</div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: this is a good question. it will not be easy to solve without a change in the database. you could do a `UNION` query to get both states into the first result. but the cities are all referencing to the same state. So you would have to change the ccode or scode for the cities or do a lot of `CASE` `WHEN` stuff in the query.

Comment: Ok the union part sounds very interesting will take a look, the second issue you mention, i need to divide categories for the first state divide A-l , so there you have only the cities with A to L should be in the first "piece" of that , just i do not know anything about union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query could be a `UNION` query like I posted. It could be something like that:

```
(
    SELECT
    (
        CASE WHEN sname = 'State 1' THEN 'State 1 A-L'
        ELSE sname
        END
    ) AS sname,
    ccode,
    scode
    FROM table_states
    WHERE ccode='MX'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
    'State 1 M-Z' AS sname,
    '01' AS ccode, /* ccode from State 1 */
    '02' AS scode  /* scode from State 1 */
)
Order by find_in_set(scode, '01,17,02,18,03,19,04,20,05,21,06,22,07,23,08,24,09,25,10,26,11,27,12,28,13,29,14,30,15,31,33,32,16')
```

I didn't test the `CASE/WHEN`. But it should rename `State 1` to `State 1 A-L`. The second query only returns the hardcoded values. And here you could hardcode other ccode or scode for `State 1 M-Z`. Then you'd have to change it in the database for the cities.

Another idea is to do the condition for the cities in PHP:

```
if ($row['sname'] == 'State 1 A-L') {
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `table_cities`
        where ccode='$row[ccode]'
        and scode='$row[scode]'
        AND city < 'M' limit 0,30";
}
else if ($row['sname'] == 'State 1 M-Z') {
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `table_cities`
        where ccode='$row[ccode]'
        and scode='$row[scode]'
        AND city > 'L' limit 0,30";
}
else {
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `table_cities`
        where ccode='$row[ccode]'
        and scode='$row[scode]' limit 0,30";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just order by `city` in your `table_cities` query? Then you could perform a simple check on whether the city name starts with a certain letter. Once you pass that letter, terminate the current submenu and start writing in a new one.

As an aside, you can accomplish all of this in a single query if you join `table_states` into your `table_cities` query and order by state first. The same technique I've outlined above will work for looping through states, terminating the current menu and starting a new one each time you find a new state.

Comment: Well because if i do that the 2 columns do not match the order set by the designer and client.. thats why i change your idea (that was the first model) to this one.. Also as i say i need to "divide" one state into two, but in the query.... because inside the site "categories", "news" "forum" all the content, must me just 1 state (the state that is divided in menu) ..